# Dragon RCS: Four controlled degrees of freedom... or six?

Tags: spacex, attitude, dragon, rcs

Would Dragon's RCS clusters allow it to translate cleanly left-right and backward-forward, like a crab? Or are they meant only for roll/pitch/yaw control + longitudinal (up/down) translation, like an airplane?

In other words, do the RCS clusters allow control over a full six degrees of freedom (x/y/z translation, x/y/z rotation), or just four degrees of freedom (x translation, x/y/z rotation)?

**EDIT**

I'm sure some RCS thruster combinations would give you a sideways translational velocity, even if this is not by design. But an incidental sideways translational velocity isn't very useful if it comes coupled with undesired rotations or translations (along other axes).

If all you need is a pure +Y translation, but that translation comes with +Z rotation and +X translation, you're in trouble if you don't cancel out those undesired motions---you wouldn't want an inadvertent yaw when you're about to dock, nor would you want to inadvertently accelerate forward and risk a harder collision with the docking port.

So what I'm asking, I guess, is this: Is there any combination of RCS thrusters that will give you *clean, *pure* left-to-right and back-to-front translation with those RCS clusters? And is this required for rendezvous, or do spacecraft normally rendezvous and dock with just the four degrees of freedom an airplane operates with?

Comment: Are you asking only about Dragon? The last paragraph doesn't seem so.  Shuttle certainly had 6 DOF control in orbit.

Comment: Aircraft operate with 6 degrees of freedom

Comment: Pure moment from force couples for x/y/z rotations... but zero moment for pure x/y/z translations... This is no problem for x translations, since there are at least two pairs of thrusters that will perfectly cancel out not just y/z translations but also x/y/z rotations (two pairs for +x translation, two pairs for -x translation, to clarify). But this is not at all clear for y/z translations. Nor is it clear for y/z rotations, by the way, but these rotations are clearly essential, and I can't imagine a spacecraft operating without control over them, so...

Comment: Can you add an image/reference showing the coordinate system on the vehicle?

Comment: Brendan, if your airplane can translate sideways without simultaneously rolling and yawing and without very strong headwinds, then you have a magical airplane. Most airplanes have control only over roll, pitch, yaw, and longitudinal velocity---meaning you can control independently for each of these variables without simultaneously change the others. You cannot generally translate an airplane sideways without changing its attitude---and even then, you'll need a lot of headwind.

Comment: You are then implying a rotating (non-inertial) reference frame

Comment: The spacecraft would generally be accelerating or rotating, so its main reference frame, being fixed it, would be non-inertial. But this seems tangential to the main question, which is about the controlled degrees of freedom of the spacecraft, and these aren't dependent on your particular choice of frame (an airplane has four controlled degrees of freedom regardless of whether you consider it in an inertial frame or in a non-inertial frame or in a quasi-inertial frame)...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming [this simulation](https://iss-sim.spacex.com/) is correct, and I have no reason to doubt that it is, there is in fact true 6 degrees of freedom of movement possible. I do recall that at least one of the axis has less control, but I can't find the news report that states how the manual control felt according to the astronauts...

Comment: Yeah... And that sim is by SpaceX, too, isn't it... I just gave it a try, and yes, you can have clean, pure Y and Z translation without undesired rotation/translation components... So if that is true to the real thing, then six degrees of freedom seems to be the answer... This was my first guess, but I just can't wrap my arms around the super weird RCS thruster orientations... I mean, there is no pair of thrusters that will give you clean Y translation... you *will* get undesired x translation and z rotation... so you have to fire up to two more thruster pairs to cancel those two motions...

Comment: Seems convoluted... and nevermind that the required throttle to cancel the unwanted Y/Z rotations will depend on the location of the center of mass, which moves very substantially as the fuel tanks empty out (and even more so when the trunk separates on return to earth).

Answer (score 1):

Each thruster will have a thrust vector.  That can be resolved into torque and translation depending on the CM.  If you have six thrusters you should be able to get all six degrees of freedom.  If you want one pure degree of freedom you have to solve a set of simultaneous equations, which is not hard.  If there is a degeneracy in the system you may not be able to get them all.  If there is almost a degeneracy it will take a lot of fuel to get one of them.

Wanting one pure degree of freedom is rare.  From a starting position, velocity, and rotation the chance you need just one is zero.  A typical design process would be to assume a range of CM positions and specify that one must be able to achieve any combination of translation and rotation up to some limit with a given amount of fuel.  You may well measure the CM in the first few burns, then update the firing schedule based on that.  If the designer placing the thruster finds it hard, s/he may push back and say that the case that is causing trouble is not likely and ask for an update to the specification.  S/he might suggest an alternative strategy to work around the problem.  SpaceX was clearly convinced that the thruster arrangement would meet the mission requirements, then was able to convince NASA of the same proposition.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ross! This is super helpful. I'd actually written a set of simultaneous equations to solve because I couldn't see any other way, but kept scratching my head as to why such a weird RCS arrangement, which gave me pause and left me questioning whether I understood what I was doing *at all*. I was half-convinced I had it all wrong and that I wasting my time. But you seem confident in what you know, and OK, I'll buckle down and go solve those equations. Thank you thank you thank you :)

Comment: Solving a $6 \times 6$ system is easy for a computer.  If you want to minimize fuel consumption over a range of missions it get harder, but you do that at home when you have lots of compute power available.  Then you pick one solution, mount the thrusters there, and produce the simulations for the design review to show you can meet the fuel requirement.  In flight you have already mounted the thrusters, so you know the locations and angles.  Now the compute requirements go way down, which is nice as your compute horsepower is down as well.

Comment: And I have questions! I'm calculating position/attitude errors in my spacecraft's axes, then feeding those errors each to a dedicated controller which will issue a command to be passed through a control allocation scheme---which will come from solving three simultaneous equations, two of them for translational DoFs and one of them for a rotational DoF (because I will only fire thrusters in pairs that are sure to result in motion on a single plane). The output from the control allocation scheme will be the thruster firing durations (which are hypergolic on/off dracos without throttling). (1/2)

Comment: So, there are twelve primary RCS thrusters for maneuvering plus another four redundant thrusters locked inside a nose cone and which I am therefore ignoring for now. This makes it 12 thrusters x 6 DoFs, all of which are predefined as I'm simply copying what I think I've learned about the Dragon spacecraft. And those thrusters have mirror symmetry about the Y and Z axes, so that if I fire them in pairs, I am guaranteed to eliminate motion in three DoFs (two rotations and one translation), which seems to reduce my equations to 6 thruster pairs x 3 DoFs... Not sure if this makes sense?

Comment: Thruster firings happen on the time scale of milliseconds, if not longer.  These days, even a flight computer can do *lots* of computation in milliseconds (don't ask about how Gemini did it).  You can certainly compute each axis independently, then add them together to get firing times for each thruster.  $12$ thrusters sounds like two sets of $6$ as redundant pairs, so you may want to only use $6$ until one fails.

Comment: Yes! That's what I expected to be able to do---redundancy is important... but the RCS clusters are not aligned with the spacecraft's X/Y/Z axes... so when I compute my attitude errors and resolve them in those axes... I wind up having to call up RCS thrusters in pairs... because there is no single thruster that will do the job. Now, this all changes naturally when I add all the commands resulting from X/Y/Z/qX/qY/qZ errors, and some thrusters will sometimes cancel out... but this will depend on the exact combination of errors... so I need all thrusters available even if none has failed...

Comment: So that is one thing that's stumped me for a while: that I seem to need to all thrusters available just in case. If any one thruster fails, I don't know that I can produce a correction for pure translation along all axes or pure rotation about all axes...

Comment: The question is not whether the thrusters are aligned to the axes, it is whether they are paired in terms of torque and force.  If they are paired, you should be able to use one of each pair.  If not, any combination of six may provide all six degrees of freedom if you solve the equations.  Wanting pure force or torque on one axis is an artifact of the coordinate system you have chosen.  It may make programming easier, but the efficient approach is to avoid it.  Find the force and torque you want in space, then resolve that into thruster effects.

Comment: But more importantly! My control allocation matrix which will come from solving my simultaneous equations: those equations depend only on fixed parameters like the locations and alignments of my thrusters as well as the lever arms from the center of mass to the individual thrusters... *except* that the X (longitudinal) component of the lever arms will change as fuel is consumed, and then again when the payload trunk is released... and so it seems that I have to update my control allocation matrix on the fly to correct for the change in CM? Could you confirm/dispute this?

Comment: Hmmm... You have a point... I mean, in the end, the most DoFs I'm controlling for is six... and that should mean that if my thrusters are properly placed I should need no more than six of them at any one time... OK, I'll have to think about this some to see it clearly. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It depends on how much the CM may move and the accuracy required.  Fuel consumption can play a role in CM movement, but so can crew movement.  I don't think that is hard at all for today's computers.  You even get data on the fly from the sensors, which tell you how much effect each thruster pulse had.

Comment: OK, so control allocation matrix will be updated on the fly. Now, how about thruster selection? One strategy seems to be to sort a list of thrusters by efficiency WRT each DoF requesting correction, then select those most suitable for the job. Would this be done on the fly, or would it be hard-coded into the spacecraft (so that if a particular DoF needs correction, then the code dictates that some RCS thruster set W should fire if it's available, to be replaced by some alternate set V if W is unavailable)? So in the second option, all possible RCS sets would be predefined in advance.

Comment: It's all in the complication of the software you want to write, qualify, and put on the spacecraft.  You trade that off against the improved efficiency of using the best thruster set for the task at hand.  I don't think there is a simple answer.

Comment: I'm still thinking in terms of DoFs WRT the spacecraft's axes, sorry. But I guess I'm wondering: is it better to figure out *in advance* the primary and backup RCS thrusters to fire for each DoF, and then just select them and skip straight to solving your simultaneous equations to get your control allocation matrix... or does it make more sense to sort through a list of available thrusters as position/attitude errors come in, then select the best from among them (so you're not bound by whatever predetermined sets you might have picked during design)?

Comment: OK, so it's a tradeoff without a straightforward answer, meaning both ways could potentially work fine, and you just have to think of some other reason to pick one over the other... I guess it seems simpler to just fix the thruster selection in advance and write it out in tables of primary and alternate thrusters each for X/Y/Z/qX/qY/qZ DoFs (sorry, still thinking in spacecraft axes), which would then be uploaded to the spacecraft for the position/attitude controllers to search through and select the best available option... maybe... I'll give it a try... Thanks *so much* for your input!

Comment: OK, so the big takeaways for me are: (1) yes, I should write and solve simultaneous equations for my DoFs with my thruster forces and moments as parameters, (2) yes, I should update my moment arms on the fly to reflect the change in CM, e.g. due to fuel consumption and trunk separation, (3) yes, it may be OK to do thruster selection in advance and simply upload thruster selection tables for use by the spacecraft's controllers in flight, and if that doesn't work, then dynamically constructing those thruster selections in flight may be OK too.